# How can I send fake sms to myself without mobile network usage?

Tags: android, sms, send

I want to show some information as an sms in my application. 
But SmsManager and BroadcastReciever can not create sms and notify on phone itself.

How can I send a fake sms to myself programmatically? Any ideas, workarounds or any class for research... ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PROOF OF CONCEPT

Call SMS list

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.setComponent(
            new ComponentName("com.android.mms","com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

READ SMS

```
cursor c= getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null ,null,null); 
        startManagingCursor(c);
        c.moveToFirst();  

            String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
            String number = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();

        c.close(); 

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), number, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Write SMS

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("address", "SENDER");
        values.put("body", "foo bar");
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), values);
```

MANIFEST

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

ISSUE
There is no event after that therefore android doesnt known if there is some new message.

Comment: May be you can try some getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
Just idea.

Comment: Yea just build your own class to launch the sms app, and display the notification to user.

Comment: this way has a problem . when i open a real sms notification  the sms app show the  "unread " status .  but if the sms is faked . it is read.

Comment: is it deprecated now?

Answer (score 1):

You can send SMS from another instance of Android Emulator. That could be done through Emulator control View in Eclipse or using [Telnet](http://www.anddev.org/video-tut_-_simulating_incoming_phone_calls_-_sms_via_cmd-t135.html).

Comment: Than you. Bu I want to do this with programmaticaly. Is there any way to send telnet sms command from android console inside according your link?

Comment: I think that you can't send SMS to Emulator from itself, and I think that there is no need  for it.